# Can trait hierarchies be matched in scala?

Tags: scala

Can matching work over a hierarchy of traits rather than classes?
Can traits be matched at all?

am I awfully inadept at writing extractors, or is there no way to match by traits rather than by classes as in the following simplified example's intent:

```
abstract trait  Abstract
trait A extends Abstract
trait B extends Abstract

class C1 extends A
class C2 extends A
class C3 extends B
class C4 extends B

object NoCompile{
  def foo(s: Abstract) = s match {
    case A =>
    case B =>
  }
}

[error] not found: value A
[error]     case A =>
[error]          ^
[error] not found: value B
[error]     case B =>
```

Reminds me a little of structural typing.

Comment: Your matches are looking for the traits' companion objects — which don't exist.

Comment: Sounds like something you should open a new question on? (What do you want it to look like? What do you want to do with it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just

```
object Compile {
  def foo(s: Abstract) = s match {
    case _ : A =>
    case _ : B =>
  }
}
```

so it can match by type, including both classes and traits:

```
object Compile {
  def foo(s: Abstract) = s match {
    case _ : A =>
    case _ : B =>
    case _ : C1 =>
  }
}
```

`_` is just a placeholder here, you can use any name capture an object itself.
Be aware that it won't work correctly for structural types, as it will always successfully match them:

```
scala> object Compile {
     |       def foo(s: Abstract) = s match {
     |         case _ : A =>
     |         case _ : B =>
     |         case _ : C =>
     |         case _ : {def a: Int} => println("Z")
     |       }
     |     }
<console>:16: warning: a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked
               case _ : {def a: Int} => println("Z")
                        ^

scala> Compile.foo(new Abstract{})
Z
```